# LuaTeX: How to prevent hyphenation from breaking opentype features?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, hyphenation

I try to create my own optimized hyphenation, but it seems that hyphenation rules affect the Opentype-features (especially ligatures defined in a font) when used with `LuaTeX` and `fontspec`. Here is a simple example, that uses only a wordbased hyphenation pattern to ensure that the reason for this issue is not a pattern mistake done by me. I searched for this in the `fontspec` manual but didn't find a hint there.
Note that the font linked in the code has a big database included using opentype-features to automatically chose the correct long s, round s, and ligatures like `longs c h` and so on. But exactly this seems to become broken when the hyphenation split appears before such a place.

**Update**: it seems to work correctly with XeTeX, so this seems like `LuaTeX` or `fontspec`-bug or limitation.

**Update 2**: `[Renderer=HarfBuzz]` solves the paticular problem as was shown by David Carlisle. Unfortunately my further test show that now other words that worked before like `Forscher` (long s expected) are now wrong. It seems that both rendering engines don't have this working.

```latex
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\usepackage{showhyphenation}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[]{LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf}%https://www.ligafaktur.de/LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf

\hyphenation{
    Fort-schritt
}

\begin{document}
    Fortschritt (without the hyphenation \texttt{Fort-schritt} the word is rendered with long s and other ligatures.)
\end{document}
```

The following image shows the expected output when no own hyphenation is used.
[image]

Now the image with hyphenation (incorrect):
[image]

Comment: For future readers: the solution is to remove all opentype features from the font and implement them in you own program. Then do [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669319/luatex-how-to-prevent-hyphenation-from-breaking-opentype-features#comment1666376_669385).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Harfbuzz in lualatex, as in xelatex

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\usepackage{showhyphenation}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf}%https://www.ligafaktur.de/LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf

\hyphenation{
    Fort-schritt
}

\begin{document}
    Fortschritt (without the hyphenation \texttt{Fort-schritt} the word is rendered with long s and other ligatures.)
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use luatex's extended hyphenation mechanism to include more letters in the discretionary

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
%\usepackage{showhyphenation}

\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont
%[Renderer=HarfBuzz]
{LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf}%https://www.ligafaktur.de/LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf

\hyphenation{
    Fort{-}{sc}{sc}hritt
}

\begin{document}
    Fortschritt (without the hyphenation \texttt{Fort-schritt} the word is rendered with long s and other ligatures.)

Fortschritt xxxxxx Fortschritt Fortschritt Fortschritt Fortschritt Fortschritt Fortschritt 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Didn't expect that a solution would be that simple :)

Comment: Update: HarfBuzz fails to :( but at other places. Now "Forscher" is wrong, which was correct before (and many others are now incorrect). So with option HarfBuzz in total it becomes worse unfortunately :(

Comment: @Guest I wondered where it would fail (no mode is perfect in all cases which is why the mode is a choice), there is a plan b though, let me try something....

Comment: the database is deterministicly defined in the font, it should not fail if renderer is implemented correctly, I assume.

Comment: @Guest that depends how you define "correct" hyphenation is handled by tex not the font, so each segment of the word is potentially passed to the font machinery as a separate string. That said it may be that luaotfload could spot this and correct for the effect, you may want to unaccept and see if Marcel is around:-) But I added a plan b which you may prefer

Comment: thank you the updated code seems to work good so far. I have not yet updated all patterns, but the words I tested work now. I implemented word splitting some time ago from zero and the longest sequence pattern should match first then one letter less and so on. That's a huge runtime complexity but the only one which is correct, I think.

Comment: @Guest actually there were some luatex fixes in related areas within the last couple of weeks,  I may try to build a new luatex...  https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2022-December/006712.html

Comment: Thanks, I noticed this a little bit during testing but this seems only to be about kerning. For my font the most important is correct ligatures. In my opinion, the example I have shown is also a (hard) bug in (at least) luatex. But most people won't recognize this (in the meaning of visually see it with their fonts), because it's only a hard problem for automatic blackletter fonts.

Comment: @Guest yes but "hyphenation splits up font metric data" is a description that would apply to both, so it's worth seeing if it fixes it or reporting it if not

Comment: Ah, okay that could actually have an impact, yes!

Comment: I think I just rebuilt luahbtex from latest source, and it doesn't fix this @Guest

Comment: Ok, thank you for trying out!

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but too long for a comment... Anyway I wanted to add some background:

- This font more or less has to look at the entire word as context to decide if a `s` or a `ſ` is used. Since it is implemented though OpenType features and these are always only using the line of the current word for context, linebreaking might generally influence if you get a `s` or a `ſ`. Since between shaping and linebreaking eveything gets written into a node structure which models TeX's classical model of fixed characters and `\discretionary`, this would often require the whole word to be rewritten into one big `\discretionary`. Given that these can't be nested this is a rather big limitation and compromises have to be made. Here the modes differ: The `node` mode (active by default) avoids these giant `\discretionary`s and instead makes less context available for font features. It still implements simple matches across hyphenation points, but no arbitrary matching as needed for this font in order to keep any line break effects contained to a few glyphs. The alternative to this is implemented in the `harf` mode: The `harf` mode tries to ensure that the font always has access to needed context, putting whole words into `\discretionary`s if needed, potentially sacrificing hyphenation points in the process.

  **tl;dr:** If you use crazy fonts with huge contextual matches like `LOV.AlteSchwabacher.ttf`, then use `harf` mode (aka. `Renderer=HarfBuzz` in fontspec aka. read David's answer). It's pretty much what that's designed for.
- You mentioned that adding `Renderer=HarfBuzz` handles some words differently, e.g. `Forscher`. The font contains not just OpenType features but also [AAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Advanced_Typography) features for the same functionality. The default renderer always uses the OpenType ones while HarfBuzz supports both and prefers AAT if both are present. This is the default handling both in CoreText (macOS) and HarfBuzz and therefore everywhere where AAT is supported. So if AAT produces worse results than the OpenType feature, then the font should just remove this AAT stuff ([Sadly HarfBuzz does not expose the option to change the preferred system](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz/issues/1391)).
- *Why* do you want to do the `s` / `ſ` translation using *font features*? It's a rather odd place for these. Font features have e.g. all this handling to avoid being influenced by characters on other lines which doesn't make any sense for this usecase since you want to handle words consistently independent of linebreaks. Since some of the distinctions depend on syllables which often correspond to hyphenation points you might even try to use the hyphenation as help rather than having to deal with their odd interaction with font features. Maybe just use Lua for this? Then it's also independent of a specific font.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already heared about AAT problems but didn't assume a relation here. I think that this is an important information that should be in the manual, that hyphenation in luatex is limited so much. Now that I know it, I of course have to implement my own lua code which will take some hundred lines. `Maybe just use Lua`. Well, I searched the `LuaTeX` docs and didn't found an example how to `just use` it for hyphenation. There was only a trivial `foobar` example, but not about patterns. Btw. a very similiar problem appears with `showhyphenation`, it also fails sometimes.

Comment: I now reimplemented the complete pattern algorithm in Rust. It can handle millions of patterns without problems - LuaTeX won't compile 300.000 patterns (CPU at 100% for minutes without progress). I then preprocess the input text in my program and the output text gets the [soft hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) and no patterns at all are set in TeX. As a nice side effect I made the pattern algorithm recursive, meaning after the first complete splitting all splits are now seen as single words where the algorithm runs on them again: making start and end patterns work again.

Comment: (I used 4 HashMaps, each one for one anchor type `.abc`, `abc.`, `.abc.`, `abc`). Probably LuaTeX uses the Trie-algorithm, which is expected to be slow nowadays.